# Append server name in a API response -- Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to create a API with Django restframework.

There is a Image field in the API which is giving a relative path. I would like to have  absolute path or name of the server to append before the Image field.

But its throwing an error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

I believe the json that I created from the ordered dict is a string and is not giving expected output.

**Problem:** I need to access the json keys and append server name in it.
I tried the following for it.

views.py

```
def get_individualmember_details(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = MasterIndividualMembersSerializer(MasterIndividualMembers.objects.all(), many=True)
        result = json.dumps(serializer.data)
        print(result)
        for row in result:
            if row["member_photos"]["image"]:
                row["member_photos"]["image"] = request.META['HTTP_HOST'] + "/" + row["member_photos"]["image"]
        result = json.dumps(result)
        return JsonResponse(json.loads(result), safe=False)
```

expected output:

```
[
    {
        "individualmemberId": "1",
        "member_photos": [
            {
                "id": 25,
                "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/individualmemberphotos/user.jpeg",   // need to append servername here
                "individualmemberId": "1"
            }
        ],
...
...
]
```

current output without the logic above:

```
[
    {
        "individualmemberId": "1",
        "member_photos": [
            {
                "id": 25,
                "image": "individualmemberphotos/user.jpeg", 
                "individualmemberId": "1"
            }
        ],
...
...
]
```

Serializer.py

```
class IndividualPhotosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IndividualMemberPhotos
        fields = "__all__"


class MasterIndividualMembersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    member_photos = IndividualPhotosSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = MasterIndividualMembers
        fields = "__all__"
```

Please suggest how to append the server name or a string before any json key.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please show what do MasterIndividualMembersSerializer and the Member Photos Serializer look like?

Comment: I edited the post and added serializers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want [absolute URL to be built for your files](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/#file-fields-as-urls), pass down the request context when instantiating your serializer. Otherwise, the file URLs are relative.

```
context = {'request': request}
serializer = MasterIndividualMembersSerializer(
    MasterIndividualMembers.objects.all(),
    context=context,
    many=True)
```

Comment: Addition to this, I got a hint from the document you share. I added ```uploaded_file = serializers.FileField(use_url=True)```, to get the absolute URL.
Thanks for the effort Oluwafemi!

Answer (score 1):

In your `IndividualPhotosSerializer`, declare the field `image` field like this:

```
class IndividualPhotosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.CharField(source='image.url')  
    # because FileField and it's child ImageField have an attribute `url` which constructs the full url from MEDIA_URL and the relative path stored in the database
    
    ... {everything else as it is}
```

Then in your `settings.py` ensure that you have an appropriate value set for `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#media-root)

Comment: Why does image have to declare a custom serializer given that DRF should already serialize it as an [ImageField](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/98e56e0327596db352b35fa3b3dc8355dc9bd030/rest_framework/fields.py#L1568)?

Comment: instead of charfield I used ```FileField``` as ```use_url= True```. I share it on Oluwagemi's comment